# Flutter load limited(20 documents) records and display in list view at a time

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a requirement to  read only 20 records at a time from Firestore and display in list view. When user click next button then I need to load next 20  documents. It is similar to paging.
Can some one help on how to do this. Any library available for this?

Comment: Can some one help to suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code limits the number of records to 3, it will load more records while scrolling the list instead of load more button starting from the last document retrieved from the cloud store

```
class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  Feed({this.firestore});

  final Firestore firestore;

  @override
  _FeedState createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  ScrollController controller;
  DocumentSnapshot _lastVisible;
  bool _isLoading;
  CollectionReference get homeFeeds => widget.firestore.collection('homefeed');
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _data = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _getData();
  }

  Future<Null> _getData() async {
//    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5));
    QuerySnapshot data;
    if (_lastVisible == null)
      data = await widget.firestore
          .collection('homefeed')
          .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
          .limit(3)
          .getDocuments();
    else
      data = await widget.firestore
          .collection('homefeed')
          .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
          .startAfter([_lastVisible['created_at']])
          .limit(3)
          .getDocuments();

    if (data != null && data.documents.length > 0) {
      _lastVisible = data.documents[data.documents.length - 1];
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          _data.addAll(data.documents);
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('No more posts!'),
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
          child: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: _data.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          if (index < _data.length) {
            final DocumentSnapshot document = _data[index];
            return new Container(
              height: 200.0,
              child: new Text(document['question']),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: new Opacity(
              opacity: _isLoading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child: new SizedBox(
                  width: 32.0,
                  height: 32.0,
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
        onRefresh: ()async{
            _data.clear();
            _lastVisible=null;
            await _getData();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (!_isLoading) {
      if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() => _isLoading = true);
        _getData();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: hi @Shyju Madathil, could you please tell what is the reference for these objects?
CollectionReference
DocumentSnapshot
Firestore

or better, if i want to use sqflite, does it mean i need only change the Firebase to my SqfLite Model right? 

tks