# Firebase's Infinite Scrolling loads entire collection at once

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to implement Firebase's Infinite scrolling through the "firebase_ui_firestore" library.
**The goal** would be to load 12 documents initially and load more once the user reaches the end.
However, **the problem** is that all documents from the collection are loaded and displayed once the screen is opened.

Could anyone help me with fixing the issue?

My code is the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_firestore/firebase_ui_firestore.dart';
import 'package:myapp/constants.dart';
import 'package:myapp/models/video_tile.dart';
import 'package:myapp/widgets/videos/profile_video_tile.dart';


class InfiniteScrollingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userUid;

  const InfiniteScrollingScreen({required this.userUid, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InfiniteScrollingScreen> createState() => _InfiniteScrollingScreenState();
}

class _InfiniteScrollingScreenState extends State<InfiniteScrollingScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final query = firestore
        .collection(videosPath)
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userUid)
        .withConverter(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => VideoTile.fromJson(snapshot),
      toFirestore: (user, _) => user.toJson(),
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: FirestoreQueryBuilder<VideoTile>(
        query: query,
        pageSize: 12,
        builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
          if (snapshot.isFetching) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong! ${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              ),
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (snapshot.hasMore && index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
                  snapshot.fetchMore();
                }

                final videoTile = snapshot.docs[index].data();

                return ProfileVideoTile(
                  thumbnailUrl: videoTile.thumbnail,
                  videoId: videoTile.id,
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried to fix the issue by removing "shrinkWrap: true", a SingleChildScrollView widget, a SafeArea widget, and a CupertinoPageScaffold widget.
I don't know how to approach this problem otherwise.

I would appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275624/flutter-load-limited20-documents-records-and-display-in-list-view-at-a-time

Comment: Your code doesn't implement pagination yet, so that explains why you get all documents. I recommend starting with the Firebase documentation on [cursor based pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and looking at some of the many existing [questions about pagination in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+pagination).

Comment: Is additional pagination required, Frank? According to the documentation from firestore (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_firestore), pageSize gives the initial number of documents and once the end was reached another batch should be loaded, at least from my understanding. I thought it might be bc of shrinkWrap expecting all documents, but I already removed it and it is still not working... Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

you can use .limit() on your query
just create new variable
and just put the variable on the limit method

```
int docLimit = 12; // initial 12    
firestore.collection(videosPath).where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userUid).limit(docLimit)....
```

and then just add the docLimit value when you scroll and hit the bottom

you can watch here as your refference [How to check if scroll position is at top or bottom in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377779/how-to-check-if-scroll-position-is-at-top-or-bottom-in-listview)